# Linq - Get Max date from resultset

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-4

I need to convert the following SQL query to Linq :-

```
 SELECT CODE,SCODE,MAX(SDATE) AS SDATE FROM SHIFTSCHEDULE 
 WHERE COMPANY = 'ABC' 
 GROUP BY CODE,SCODE 
 ORDER BY MAX(SDATE) 
 DESC
```

So far, I have tried this :-

```
var data = ctx.ShiftSchedule.Where(m =>
                                    m.Company == company && m.EmployeeId == item.EmployeeId
                                )
                                .GroupBy(m =>
                                    new
                                    {
                                        m.EmployeeId,
                                        m.ShiftId
                                    })
                                .Select(m =>
                                new
                                {
                                    EmployeeId = m.Key.EmployeeId,
                                    ShiftCode = m.Key.ShiftId,
                                    ShiftDate = m.Max(gg => gg.ShiftDate)
                                }).ToList();
```

The results i get are :-

[image]

Now what i want is to get record or item in this result set which is `MaxDate`. In the above image the MaxDate is 1st record.

How to get the `MAXDATE` from the resultset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:-

```
var data = ctx.ShiftSchedule.Where(x => x.Company == company 
                                        && x.EmployeeId == item.EmployeeId)
                            .GroupBy(x => new { x.CODE, x.SCODE })
                            .Select(x => new 
                                        {
                                            CODE = x.Key.CODE,
                                            SCODE = x.Key.SCODE,
                                            SDATE  = x.Max(z => z.SDATE) 
                                        })
                            .OrderByDescending(x => x.SDATE).FirstOrDefault();
```

You can order the resulting collection and fetch the first object using `FirstOrDefault`.

If you want just `MAXDATE`, you can only project that.

Comment: Is it `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescending`?

Comment: @Anup - Oops, It should be `OrderByDescending`.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `.OrderByDescending(x => x.ShiftDate).First();` at the end.

`OrderByDescending` date and then take `.First()`

```
 var data = ctx.ShiftSchedule.Where(m =>
                                        m.Company == company && m.EmployeeId == item.EmployeeId
                                    )
                                    .GroupBy(m =>
                                        new
                                        {
                                            m.EmployeeId,
                                            m.ShiftId
                                        })
                                    .Select(m =>
                                    new
                                    {
                                        EmployeeId = m.Key.EmployeeId,
                                        ShiftCode = m.Key.ShiftId,
                                        ShiftDate = m.Max(gg => gg.ShiftDate)
                                    }).ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x.ShiftDate).First();
```